# Drupal Commerce Product image is not shown in View Mode Node:Product List

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-commerce, drupal-content-types

I'm starting with Commerce Kickstart 2 together with demo store.

I added a product and upload one image, this product has one of the demo store variation types (Bags & Cases) and the product display type associated.

It seems simple since I didn't change nothing. But when I click in main menu the products already there are listed fine, with product image, only my new product don't show the image.

I see in variation types Bags & Cases that the Images field, Column Format, is defined as image delta, Image style: product_medium. And that is the point. In MySite/sites/default/files/styles directory are the styles of images. In that directory there is the product_medium directory where the images showed when in View Mode Node:Product list (the list of bags listed when click in To carry).

Well, the fact is when I create the product there is no option to load an image that will saved in MySite/sites/default/files/styles/product_medium directory. And that's the problem. Since when I manually copy the image to that directory, the image is showed up.

Where I define this product_medium image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to manually copy the images. 'product_medium' is an image style, which is already created when you automatically installed the demo store. So, once you  upload an image, the image will be saved in the product_medium folder.

Are you sure that you have given correct permissions to the sites/default/files directory, which being the full permission?

Comment: That's correct @Chithra, I've given correct permissions now and all is fine. Thanks!